# Use a comparison between $\chi^2$ and Gamma to solve find $E(x^k)$ and $E(1/x)$?

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X\sim\chi^2_n$ be a random variable with a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

> (I) Derive $E[X^k]$ for general $k > −n/2$.
>
> (II) Find $E[1/X]$.

This exercise has the following hint: instead of evaluating an integral

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} x^{r-1} \, dx
$$

of the form compare it to the density of the gamma distribution, which we know integrates to one. It’s ok to use the fact that a χ2-random variable is a special case of the gamma distribution.

I was trying to do the comparison the hint said but I have no clue how to derived  point I and II for this exercise. Thanks.

---

I follow the guide bellow

I have that the $f(x) = \left( \frac 1 2\right)^{n/2} x^{(n/2)-1} {e^{-x/2}} {r(n/2)}$
I plug it in the expression of

$$E(X^k)= \int_0^\infty x^k \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n/2} x^{(n/2)-1} \frac{e^{-x/2}}{r(n/2)} \, dx. $$

Now I'm stuck again, I believe I need to compare with the $X^2$ but I'm not sure what I need to compare to obtain the $E\{x\}$. Thanks, and sorry if is a lame question, but I'm trying without susses to finish this exercise.Thanks, again.

Comment: Use this $ E[g(x)] = \int_o^{\infty} g(x) f_X(x) ~ dx$

You don't have to do the integration coz it'll require integration by parts. Just compare it to the PDF of a Gamma distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution
and replace it appropriately with constants.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139511/6633) on stats.SE for how to find $E[X^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gamma density with shape $r$ and rate $\lambda$ has the form $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\lambda^r e^{-\lambda y} y^{r-1} }{\Gamma(r)}, \quad y > 0.$$  The hint tells you that you may assume two facts:  $$\int_{y = 0}^\infty f_Y(y) \, dy = 1,$$ and $$X \sim \chi^2_n \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(r = n/2, \lambda = 1/2).$$  Now we write $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \int_{x=0}^\infty x^k f_X(x) \, dx,$$ and use the above facts to evaluate the integral.  Once you do this, you can also evaluate $\operatorname{E}[1/X]$ by setting $k = -1$, with the caveat that $n > 2$.

---

We write $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X^k] &= \int_{x=0}^\infty  \frac{x^{k+n/2-1} e^{-x/2}}{2^{n/2} \Gamma(n/2)} \, dx \\ &= \frac{2^k \Gamma(k+n/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)} \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+n/2-1} e^{-x/2}}{2^{k+n/2} \Gamma(k+n/2)} \, dx\end{align*}$$ and recognize that the integrand is now the density of a gamma distribution with rate $\lambda = 1/2$ and shape $r = k+n/2$, and thus integrates to $1$.  It follows that the expectation is $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \frac{2^k \Gamma(k+n/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}, \quad k > -n/2,$$ with the restriction on $k$ due to the fact that the new shape parameter $r = k+n/2$ must be positive.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding how to evaluate such integral, I posted my work above but I can't see how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. If I didn't misunderstand the final value of E[1/X] will be n dependent, no? (with k=-1)

Comment: @Electro82 Of course it must be, since $n$ is the degrees of freedom for the chi-square distribution, so it is natural to expect that the expectation will vary as a function of $n$.

Comment: To calculate E{1/X} after plug k=-1, I have E[1/X]=1/2*GAMA((N/2)-1)/GAMA((N/2))=(2/(N-2))*1/2=1/N-2. Is that possible correct?

Comment: @Electro82 yes, $$\operatorname{E}[1/X] = \frac{1}{n-2},$$ for $n > 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\Gamma(r) = \int_0^\infty u^{r-1} e^{-u}\,du.
$$
Hence
$$
\Gamma(r) = \int_0^\infty \left(\lambda w \right)^{r-1} e^{-\lambda w} (\lambda \, dw).
$$
So the Gamma distribution is
$$
 \frac{\left(\lambda w \right)^{r-1} e^{-\lambda w} (\lambda \, dw)}{\Gamma(r)} \text{ on }(0,\infty).
$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(X^k) = \int_0^\infty w^k\ \frac{(\lambda w)^{r-1} e^{-\lambda w} (\lambda \, dw)}{\Gamma(r)} & = \frac 1 {\lambda^k \Gamma(r)} \int_0^\infty (\lambda w)^k\ (\lambda w)^{r-1} e^{-\lambda w} (\lambda \, dw) \\[12pt]
& = \frac 1 {\lambda^k \Gamma(r)} \int_0^\infty u^{r+k-1} e^{-u}\,du \\[12pt]
& = \frac 1 {\lambda^k \Gamma(r)} \Gamma(r+k) \\[12pt]
& = \frac {r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+k-1)} {\lambda^k}.
\end{align}